# Reading email address from contacts fails with weird memory issue

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, addressbook, contacts

I'm stumped.

I'm trying to get a list of all the email address a person has.
I'm using the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` to select the person, which all seems fine. I'm setting my

```
ABRecordRef personDealingWith;
```

from the `person` argument to

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
```

and everything seems fine up till this point.
The first time the following code executes, all is well.
When subsequently run, I can get issues. First, the code:

```
// following line seems to make the difference (issue 1)
// NSLog(@"%d", ABMultiValueGetCount(ABRecordCopyValue(personDealingWith, kABPersonEmailProperty)));

// construct array of emails
ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(personDealingWith, kABPersonEmailProperty);
CFIndex emailCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);

if (emailCount > 0) {
    // collect all emails in array
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < emailCount; i++) {
        CFStringRef emailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);
        [emailArray addObject:(NSString *)emailRef];
        CFRelease(emailRef);
    }
}

// following line also matters (issue 2)
CFRelease(multi);
```

If compiled as written, the are no errors or static analysis problems. This crashes with a

`*** -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4e9dc60`

error.

**But wait, there's more!** I can fix it in either of two ways.

Firstly, I can uncomment the NSLog at the top of the function. I get a leak from the NSLog's `ABRecordCopyValue` every time through, but the code seems to run fine.

Also, I can comment out the

```
CFRelease(multi);
```

at the end, which does exactly the same thing. Static compilation errors, but running code.

So without a leak, this function crashes. To prevent a crash, I need to haemorrhage memory. Neither is a great solution.

Can anyone point out what's going on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turned out that I wasn't storing the `ABRecordRef personDealingWith` var correctly. I'm still not sure how to do that properly, but instead of having the functionality in another routine (performed later), I'm now doing the grunt-work in the delegate method, and using the derived results at my leisure. The new (working) routine:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    // as soon as they select someone, return
    personDealingWithFullName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
    personDealingWithFirstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    // construct array of emails
    [personDealingWithEmails removeAllObjects];
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(multi) > 0) {
        // collect all emails in array
        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); i++) {
            CFStringRef emailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);
            [personDealingWithEmails addObject:(NSString *)emailRef];
            CFRelease(emailRef);
        }
    }
    CFRelease(multi);
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. The problem might lie at how you set your

```
ABRecordRef personDealingWith;
```

It seems that you can't just do:

```
ABRecordRef personDealingWith = person;
```

Because personDealingWith remains null. Instead what I did is:

```
ABRecordID personID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
personDealingWith = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, personID);
```